# Question about simply connectedness

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification, fundamental-groups

Let $X$ be a path connected space. I have to prove the following:

> If each $f \in \mathcal{C}(\mathbb{S}^1;X)$ is homotopic to a constant map, then $\pi_1(X)$ is trivial ($X$ is simply connected) .

I am trying to prove by using this result:

> Let $(Y,\mathcal{T}_Y)$ and $(Z,\mathcal{T}_Z)$ topological spaces and $\sim$ a equivalence relation on $Y$. If $f\in \mathcal{C}(Y;Z)$ then the map $\tilde{f}:Y/_\sim \hookrightarrow Z, \tilde{f}[y]=f(y)$ is continous and $f=\tilde{f} \circ p$ where $p$ is the canonical quotient projection.

So, in order to prove it denote $I:=[0,1]$ and let $x_0 \in X$ and $\alpha \in \mathcal{C}(I;X):\alpha(0)=\alpha(1)=x_0$ . Consider $\sim$ the equivalence relation such that
$$x \sim y \iff x=y \lor x,y \in \{0,1\} $$

It is well known that with this relation, we can identify $I/_\sim$ with $\Bbb{S}^1$, so we can see the corresponding $\tilde{\alpha}$ as a map from $\Bbb{S}^1$ to $X$. Then, by the hypothesis, we have that $\tilde{\alpha}$ is homotopic to a constant map. In other words:
$$\exists \tilde{H} \in \mathcal{C}(\Bbb{S}^1 \times I ; X),  \forall x \in \Bbb{S}^1 : \tilde{H}(x,0) = \tilde{\alpha}(x) \land \tilde{H}(x,1) = c \in X$$

Since every couple of constant maps are homotopic, we can take $x_0$ as $c$ .

Consider $H : I \times I \hookrightarrow X, (t,s) \mapsto \tilde{H}(p(t),s)$ which is clearly contiunous and
$$\forall t \in I : H(t,0) = \tilde{H}(p(t),0) = \tilde{\alpha}(p(t)) = \alpha(t) \land H(t,1) = x_0$$

The problem is that I do not know how I can claim that for all $s \in I: H(0,s)=x_0=H(1,s)$ in order to say that $H$ is a path homotopy, so any possible help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I think that it can be solved if we used this result:

> Given $X,Y$ topological spaces and $f,g \in \mathcal{C}(X;Y)$ with $\varphi$ an homotopy between them, the induced homomorphisms $f_{\ast}, g_{\ast}$ satisfies $f_{\ast} = \beta_h \circ g_{\ast}$ where $h = \varphi (x_0, -)$ for some fixed $x_0 \in X$ and $\beta_h = [h] \ast - \ast [h']$ where $h'$ denotes the inverse path of $h$ .

I proved that $\tilde{\alpha}$ is homotopic to $k_{x_0}$ ( the map which assings $x_0$ to each $p\in \Bbb{S}^1$ ). Then, by the result :

$$\tilde{\alpha}_{\ast} = \beta_h \circ k_{x_0 \ast} \Rightarrow \forall \gamma \in \pi_1(\Bbb{S}^1) : \tilde{\alpha}_{\ast} ([\gamma]) = \beta_h \circ k_{x_0 \ast} ([\gamma]) = \beta_h ([c_{x_0}]) = [h \ast c_{x_0} \ast h' ] = [c_{x_0}]$$

Then, $\tilde{\alpha}_{\ast}$ is the trivial homomorphism. Now, note that $p : I \hookrightarrow I/_\sim$ is in fact a path on $\Bbb{S}^1$ via the identification $\Bbb{S}^1 = I/_\sim$. Therefore, we have:

$$[\alpha] = [\tilde{\alpha} \circ p] = \tilde{\alpha}_{\ast} ([p]) = [c_{x_0}]$$

and this conclude the proof. Is this fine?

Comment: [here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519422/a-confusion-about-the-fact-that-contractible-spaces-are-simply-connected?rq=1)

Comment: @FShrike uhm but it is true? in the proof of the claim that could help here the user uses a fact that is false, so, I am not really sure. in fact, someone comments in their answer that the claim is false. It would be true if the space was contractible, but this is not necesarily the case

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is true. The linked post (or rather, the author of the textbook) made the critical error of stating the result with the unit interval. Trivially, any map $I\to X$ is homotopic to any other so the result erroneously claims every loop is homotopic to every other...

But if you are more careful and work with $S^1$, which I expect the author had intended, then it *is* true that "all maps $S^1\to X$ are homotopic iff. $X$ is simply connected". Warning: this is a nice and a *surprising* thing; it is not true in general that "all maps $Y\to X$ are nullhomotopic" implies "all maps $Y\to X$ are nullhomotopic rel. $\{y\}$".

This would follow from the more important result:

> If $f:S^n\to X$ is nullhomotopic, then it is nullhomotopic rel. $\{s\}$ for any fixed $s$.

The proof - well, I'm sure this features elsewhere on the site, I think I've even written it myself before - goes as follows:

> Note $D^{n+1}$ "is" the quotient of $S^n\times I/(S^n\times\{0\})$ (polar coordinates). Thus a nullhomotopy of $f$ (*not* necessarily relative to anything) is "just" a map $G:D^{n+1}\to X$ such that $G(x)=f(x/\|x\|)$ for $x$ on the boundary sphere.
>
> So, we are given such a $G$. Then we use a clever squashing map, that is, a quotient $\Gamma:D^{n+1}\twoheadrightarrow D^{n+1}$ which exhibits $D^{n+1}$ as the *reduced* cone of $S^n$. Specifically $\Gamma(r,\theta)=r\cdot\theta+(1-r)\cdot s$ in polar coordinates (this is the convex combination connecting a point $(r,\theta)$ to the point $s$ on the boundary sphere). $\Gamma$ fixes the boundary and computes the quotient $D^{n+1}/[0,s]\cong D^{n+1}$.
>
> The composite $G\circ\Gamma:D^{n+1}\to X$ then induces a nullhomotopy of $f$ with now the special property that it is constant on $\{s\}\times I$. That is, $f$ is nullhomotopic rel $\{s\}$ which is exactly what we want.

Since $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ "is" the homotopy classes of maps $(S^1,s)\to(X,x_0)$ rel. $s$ (for any $s$, it doesn't matter - up to isomorphism) we get the original claim.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have some questions because you are using things that I am not used to use. First, if I am not wrong, what I learned is that $D^{n+1}$ can be identified with $S^n \times I / _\sim$ where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation that identifies all points of $S^n \times \{0\}$ to one and $S^n \times \{1\}$ to another one, I suppose that what you are using is also correct but I do not know why.

Comment: Second, I do not see why $\Gamma$ computes that quotient, moreover I do not understand why $\Gamma$ is a quotient map.

Comment: @Superdivinidad You are misremembering. The quotient $(S^n\times I)/_{\sim}$ you describe is actually homeomorphic to $S^{n+1}$, what I said is correct and produces $D^{n+1}$ instead (really it’s just polar coordinates!). $\Gamma$ is a quotient map for the abstract continuous surjection of compact Hausdorff spaces reason. Hopefully you can see $\Gamma(r,s)=s$ for all $r$? Then you might need to fiddle around to show $\Gamma$ doesn’t identify any more points but that’s unimportant. For your question the only important point is that $\Gamma$ fixes boundary and is constant on the ray $0\to s$.

Comment: you are right, thank you for correct my mistake. I am trying to understand what you say about $\Gamma$ but it is difficult for me. Anyway, thank you so much for your explanation!

Comment: @Superdivinidad Problem: the homotopy doesn’t necessarily fix $s$. Solution: compose the homotopy with a map that fixes $s$ (and keeps the boundary ie makes sure the map at the end of the homotopy is still $f$). Concrete solution: consider $G\circ\Gamma$ instead of $G$.